# we.config and cakephp applications

Tags: php, iis, cakephp

Is there a way to use web.config to replace .htaccess for a cakephp app on iis?

current .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

UPDATE:

Used import in IIS6. It gives me this web.config, but site does not work. I get a white screen. Also tried this http://book.cakephp.org/revisions/view/19937/URL-Rewrites-on-IIS7-Windows-hosts, and it didnt work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Microsoft URL Rewrite module for IIS. It'll let you import your apache rewrite rules. You can find the module here:

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

I use it with CakePHP on IIS 7.0 and 7.5 and it works a treat.

**EDIT**

Can you try this configuration for me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/webroot/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, though i heard IIS 7 has URL rewriting built in and it could use a web.config file. Have you heard that?

Comment: I don't believe it's installed as standard however, if it's not installed you can download it using the Web Platform Installer or by following the link I gave you. Once it's installed you can begin adding rules by double clicking on the "URL Rewrite" icon in the IIS section of IIS manager. The rules you enter there are stored in the web.config file.

Comment: Did this help you? Can I assist any more?

Comment: @madphp Can I help any more with this?